# how to execute a script in parallel from a c program

Tags: c

I want to execute a script from a c program which I want that it should run in parallel. So for that I have written this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
      pthread_t hwdiagT;
     if(pthread_create(&hwdiagT, NULL, &hwdiagScriptExecution, NULL) == ERROR)
    {
          printf("%s():pthread_cretation failed for hwdiag script execution",__func__);
    }

}

void *hwdiagScriptExecution()
{
/* run diags after rpd hw is up*/
    FILE *pp;
    pp=popen("/usr/bin/hwdiag allquick", "w");
    if ( pp == NULL ) {
        printf("ERROR: Couldn't run hardware diagnostics.");
    }
    else {
        pclose(pp);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

For parallel execution, I tried to put the script in a thread but seems like it is not working. Looks like this thread get block until whole script executes. Is there any way to achieve this parallel execution of script.

Comment: How do you know that it gets blocked? I don't see anything that would you tell you that this is the case

Comment: I'm also wondering if your code even completely executes since you didn't join the thread or in another way waited for it to finish